# How to prevent container to autoscroll when a partially-visible child control got focus?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus, autoscroll

A panel with enabled scrollbars has many buttons. If I push the tabulation key, focus navigates between buttons.

When a partially visible button has focus, the panel scrolls itself in order to completely show the button.

Is there a way to prevent that scrolling?

Comment: Why in the world would you **not** want that? If a button has the focus, it's what the user is focusing on. They should be able to see the whole thing. Imagine if it said "Format Drive"; they'd probably want to be able to read it clearly before pressing `Enter`.

Comment: Just because when a user clicks on the scrollbar, I do NOT want the button to be displayed entirely on mouse down, and re-partially displayed on mouse up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to create your own Panel control and override the `ScrollToControl` method:

```
Public Class PanelEx
  Inherits Panel

  Protected Overrides Function ScrollToControl(activeControl As Control) As Point
    Return Me.AutoScrollPosition
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: dude Thank you A lot!